# How to get Typeface reference to a WebView system bundled font? (Georgia, Times New Roman..)

Tags: android, webview, textview, typeface

I am making a reader type application which uses a webview to render text, user can change fonts, so say Georgia or Times New Roman, with seem to be bundled with the system (or webview atleast). This works well.

But *I want to use Georgia on android view (settings button as to change the font). **Is there a way to get a reference to "Georgia", or "Times New Roman" in android so it can be used on a TextView?***

`Typeface.create("Georgia", 0)` doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Ok Ive figured it out, font name has to be lower case

```
Typeface.create("georgia", 0)
Typeface.create("times new roman", 0)
```